# How to transfer and update existing data in a master excel file from multiple excel file

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have a task which require me to transfer (Copy&paste) and update any existing data in the master excel file from multiple excel file in a specific folder by clicking on a button. Currently, I am able to create a code which allow me to transfer (copy&paste) data from multiple excel file in a specific folder to a master excel file, but it will not update any existing data in the master excel file. Could anyone take a look at my code and help me create a code which will transfer and update any existing data in the master excel file from multiple excel file in a specific folder by click on a button ? Much appreciate any help, Thanks.

**My current code:**

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Dim lr As Long
Filepath = "C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\MultiFileTesting\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "TestingMaster.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'ActiveWorkbook.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 11))

MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code running in the "master" workbook, and is it named "TestingMaster.xlsm" ?

Comment: Could you help to try comment out `ActiveWorkbook.Close` and set the `ThisWorkbook.Activate`?

Comment: Yes, the code is running in the "Master" workbook and it is name "TestingMaster.xlsm

Comment: So currently whenever I update any existing data in any of the multiple excel file, and when i click on the button in my master file to transfer and update it data, the updated data will just be copy & paste to the bottom of the existing data in the master file. I wish to have the existing data to be updated instead of having it being paste at the bottom.

Comment: How will the code know where to paste the data from each flie?

Comment: The headers in my master file is the same as the rest of the multiple excel file, so the code will copy the entire data from the excel file and paste it into the master file. It will loop through every excel file that i have specified in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand exactly what is your problem with this code, but let's give it a try.

1) You probably don't want to end whole script when `MyFile = TestingMaster.xlsm`, just skip it.

2) You probably want to loop over some particular type of files only, like "xlsm" or "xlsx"

3) Don't know why are you using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `ThisWorkbook.Activate`

4) You need to store your "master" file name to be able to return to it with `Windows(mainName).Activate`. I have assigned it to variable by `mainName = ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

5) I don't know the structure of your source files, but maybe you need to use some particular name of worksheet (`Sheets("MySheet").`) or it's position (`Sheets(1).`) instead of `ActiveSheet.`.

6) I recommend to use `PasteSpecial` instead of `Paste`. You can paste only values if you want by changing `xlPasteAll` for `xlPasteValues`

7) You need to close source file without saving with `Workbooks(MyFile).Close False`.

The example code after this changes looks like:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Dim lr As Long
Dim mainName As String

mainName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Filepath = "C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\MultiFileTesting\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile <> "TestingMaster.xlsm" And Right(MyFile, 4) = "xlsm" Then
        Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
        lastrow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn = Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
        Windows(mainName).Activate
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Sheet1.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Workbooks(MyFile).Close False
    End If

    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In short, I basically need to get copied data from multiple excel file in a specific folder and paste it while updating any existing data in the master excel file. I've found a code that could help me but the code could only copy data from one excel file at a time and I require to open the excel file otherwise the code won't run properly. I added the new code I've found in a new comment

Answer (score 0):

**CODE**

```
    Sub import_tickets()`

    "run this when the active file is the main ticket list and the active sheet is the ticket list"

    "exported file must be open already, and the ticket list must be the active sheet"

    Dim exported_file As String
    exported_file = "20150818_PDCA_Salwa-14-SENT.xlsx"
    header_exists = True 'if exported file doesn't have a header, set this to false!
    starting_row = 1
    If header_exists Then starting_row = 2`

    Dim first_blank_row As Long
    first_blank_row = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Dim r As Long
    r = starting_row
    Dim found As Range
    cur_ticket_num = Workbooks(exported_file).ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
    Do While Not cur_ticket_num = ""
        'look for current ticket number in main file
        Set found = Columns("a:a").Find(what:=cur_ticket_num, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If found Is Nothing Then
            'add info to end of main file
            write_line_from_export exported_file, r, first_blank_row
            first_blank_row = first_blank_row + 1
        Else
            'overwrite existing line of main file
            write_line_from_export exported_file, r, found.Row
        End If
        r = r + 1
        cur_ticket_num = Workbooks(exported_file).ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
    Loop
End Sub

Sub write_line_from_export(src_filename As String, src_r As Long, dest_r As Long)
    For c = 1 To 24
        Cells(dest_r, c).Value = Workbooks(src_filename).ActiveSheet.Cells(src_r, c).Value
    Next c
End Sub
```